# Authenticating gcloud sdk with workload identity federation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts, workload-identity

I am trying to authenticate a service account by `gcloud auth login` command using workload identity federation based on whats mentioned in [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing) official tutorial. Even though the tutorial says both service account keys and workload identity federation works for my use case, WIF is the preferred route forward using [credential configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation#generate-automatic). But I am quite confused trying to generate the file for my use case as doing so requires me to create a workload identity provider which are categorized to be among the following types:
AZURE,AWS,OIDC,SAML.  I just want to use WIF to authenticate gcloud SDK from my terminal so I am not sure which category should I use.

Is this a possible use case or should I resort to use service account keys ?

But I am quite confused trying to generate the file for my use case as doing so requires me to create a workload identity provider which are categorized to be among the following types:
AZURE,AWS,OIDC,SAML.  I just want to use WIF to authenticate gcloud SDK from my terminal so I am not sure which category should I use.

Is this a possible use case or should I resort to use service account keys ?

Comment: When you say "your terminal", is your your personal computer? Or a server on AWS Azure or other platform that you want to authenticate with WIF?

Comment: I meant my Personal computer. Like I have setup a GCP project and I want to be able to run commands from my terminal to trigger actions on the project like push and pull images and what not.

Comment: `gcloud auth login` to use your user account with the gcloud CLI. `gcloud auth application-default login` to use your user account with the Google Cloud libraries (i.e. with your code)

Comment: What if I want to use gcloud CLI but by authenticating using a service account? Is that possible ? Or since service accounts are meant for machine to machine communication, I can authenticate through service account only if I am doing so within an app and not directly through CLI ?

Comment: same with that additional parameter `--impersonate-service-account=<email of the service account>`. Note that your user must have the "service account token creator" role to be able to impersonate the service account (that role must be bind on the service account itself or higher in the hierarchy (project, folder, organisation))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workload Identity Federation(WIF), is used in multi-cloud environments and hybrid cloud environments where one needs access to one cloud platform from another cloud platform or from a data center as the services are catered across multiple platforms and needs coordination for running your application.

There are multiple ways to connect other cloud providers with GCP, you can use **WIF** for connecting with Amazon Web Services (AWS),  you could use OpenID Connect (OIDC) or SAML 2.0 to connect with any other cloud providers, such as Microsoft Azure. Refer to the source for more information. (Source: [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation))

Since you are trying to connect to gcloud SDK from your terminal you can simply use your credential file or `gcloud auth` or `gcloud init` commands for setting up the gcloud cloud SDK and have necessary roles and permissions enabled for the service or user account which you are using for authentication. This is the simplest way to access your gcp environment. **JFYI**, in **[Authorize the gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing)** documentation(the doc which you were referring to) they are using the credential file which is different from WIF, so if you want to authenticate without using **SA**(service account) you can simply follow credential file based authentication.

Comment: @svs is your issue resolved revert back if you need any additional help. Upvote or accept this solution so that it can be useful for remaining community members.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was aware gcloud auth and gcloud init would let me authenticate via terminal, but I was wondering if it is even possible to autheticate to SDK from terminal using WI since I came across a situation where I thought I had to do it.Turns out it was a misunderstanding and I did not have to do that. but since the question particularly brings up the topic would you be able to confirm that?

Comment: @svs you can't use WI like gcloud auth since it requires some additional parameters and is only built for cross platform authentication.