# Why is cloud.google.com/go/functions Golang package not able to List gen2 golang functions

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to listFunctions via golang SDK using service account json .
The return iterator have information about gen1 functions but not gen2.
https://go.dev/play/p/ZwZ-jGscFCl - Please add service account json for running in local.

The same service account credentials are used for with gcloud binary. It is able to fetch all the functions.

Is there any issue with golang SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 1 answer and 1 remark

Answer:

Use the [v2 of the API in Golang](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/functions/apiv2) and not the V1. The V1 does not support environment generation variable. [Here the API spec of the V2](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.functions). Look at the environment enum.

Since 2 weeks, the V2 API also supports gen1 functions. You can get all in the same time with the same library.

Remark:

You don't need and you shouldn't (**mustn't**) use service account key file locally. Your user account (with or without service account impersonation) is made for that. Look at [my comments in that questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356621/authenticating-gcloud-sdk-with-workload-identity-federation?noredirect=1#comment132984212_75356621)